# Creating a Makefile for C++ and C source code

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am working on a project and I am at the stage where I need to compile two scripts together on a Linux machine, one .C and one C++.

The C++ code controls a camera and has been supplied with a makefile from the manufacturer to compile `GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp` using drivers installed on the computer.

What I am trying to do is to start by putting a test function `function.c` into `GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp` by including a header file, `function.h`. `function.c` contains a single function called `printtest` which prints something to the screen to show it works and I have called it from `GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp`.

Here is the original makefile:

```
SOURCES = GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "debug"
 CPPFLAGS = -D_DEBUG -ggdb3 -O0
 TGT = GrabConsoleExample_d 
 CONFIGURATION = Debug
else 
 CPPFLAGS = -O3 
 TGT = GrabConsoleExample 
 CONFIGURATION = Release
endif

CPPFLAGS += -I$(CVB)/include
LDFLAGS = -L$(CVB)/lib
LDLIBS= -lCVCImg -lCVCUtilities -lCVCDriver -lCVGenApi
CONFIGURATIONPREFIX= ./$(CONFIGURATION)/
DEPENDENCIES= $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d) )  

%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(CONFIGURATION)
    @echo Building CXX object $(CONFIGURATION)/$@
    @$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(CONFIGURATION)/$@ $<

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) )

$(TGT): $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) 
    @echo Linking CXX executable $(CONFIGURATION)/$(TGT)
    @$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(CONFIGURATION)/$(TGT) $(LDLIBS)

all: $(TGT)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf Debug
    @rm -rf Release

debug: $(TGT)
```

Here is the altered makefile:

```
CXXSOURCES = GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp
CSOURCES = function.c

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "debug"
 CPPFLAGS = -D_DEBUG -ggdb3 -O0
 TGT = GrabConsoleExample_d 
 CONFIGURATION = Debug
else 
 CPPFLAGS = -O3 
 TGT = GrabConsoleExample 
 CONFIGURATION = Release
endif

CPPFLAGS += -I$(CVB)/include
LDFLAGS = -L$(CVB)/lib
LDLIBS= -lCVCImg -lCVCUtilities -lCVCDriver -lCVGenApi
CONFIGURATIONPREFIX= ./$(CONFIGURATION)/
DEPENDENCIES= $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(CXXSOURCES:.cpp=.d) $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(CSOURCES:.c=.d))  

%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(CONFIGURATION)
    @echo Building CXX object $(CONFIGURATION)/$@
    @$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(CONFIGURATION)/$@ $<
%.o: %.c
    @echo Building CC object $(CONFIGURATION)/$@
    @$(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) -o $(CONFIGURATION)/$@ $<

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(CXXSOURCES:.cpp=.o) ) $(addprefix $(CONFIGURATIONPREFIX),$(CSOURCES:.c=.o)) #this edit without TGT edit below causes ./Release/function.o: No such file or directory

$(TGT): $(CXXSOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)
    @echo Linking CXX executable $(CONFIGURATION)/$(TGT)
    @$(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(CONFIGURATION)/$(TGT) $(LDLIBS)
#g++ -Ldir Grabconsole.o function.o -o Release/GrabConsole -lCVC...

all: $(TGT)

    .PHONY: clean
    clean:
        @rm -rf Debug
        @rm -rf Release

   debug: $(TGT)
```

This is what is returned through terminal:

```
lab_user@ubuntu12:~/Documents/iScope$ make all
Building CXX object Release/GrabConsoleExampleMain.o  
Linking CXX executable Release/GrabConsoleExample
./Release/GrabConsoleExampleMain.o: In function `process_image_pair(int, int, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*, double*)':
GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `printtest()'
./Release/GrabConsoleExampleMain.o: In function `main':
GrabConsoleExampleMain.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16c): undefined reference to `printtest()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [GrabConsoleExample] Error 1
```

I have looked at writing my own makefile but I am unsure about how to integrate it with what the camera manufacturer has supplied. I am aware that using g++ to compile the C and C++ codes together should work, so I think the error must be in the $(TGT): line of the code.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it, and let me know if you need any more information from me.

Thanks

Comment: Which error do you get with your altered version specifically? [Please add it verbatim to your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29330938/edit).

Comment: Be sure you've marked your C function as `extern "C"` in the header file.  Otherwise it won't work to link it with C++ code.

Comment: thanks πάντα ῥεῖ updated my post for you

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, the problem was as n.m. suggested with the header file. Not only did it not include `extern "C"` but also the `#indef` and `#define` parameters at the top.